# Consuming Oauth2 protected resources from C# Windows Service WITHOUT Client Credentials Flow

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, windows-services

I have an existing Windows Service C# application that has been pulling data from a REST API for a couple years using "API Key" authentication.

Recently the owner of the REST API informed us that we needed to switch to Oauth 2.0.  The problem (for me) is that they told us that even though our Windows Service is obviously a "confidential client", that they will NOT be supporting Client Credentials Flow.   I think this is because 99% of their API users are some form of in-browser app.

Can anyone provide an example of how to deal with a OAuth 2 flow that requires a Redirect URI when the client is a C# Dot Net Windows Service ?

Even after viewing the video and Googling the crap out of this, I still feel lost on how to approach the problem.